# how would I close a jQuery dialog when I click on something inside of it?

Tags: jquery

how would i close a jquery dialog when I click on something inside of the dialog?

```
$('content_in_the_dialog').click(function(){


  close the dialog

});
```

something like that. SO my question is what code should I input in there to close the dialog?

Comment: @JuanMendes jQuery kind I guess, OP title says jQuery dialog

Comment: @Ronny, you mean `jQuery UI`, which is not `jQuery` itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call close method like below,

```
$('#dialog_selector').dialog('close');
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-close